# how to get instance name of a movieClip dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I have movieClips (suppose= A) on stage. i need to modify them when i drop a moviclip (suppose= B) in a movieclip (suppose= C).

My code is

```
var stX:Number;
var stY:Number;

Ant.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Objdrag);
Ant.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ObjdropinPenta);

function Objdrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stX = e.currentTarget.x;
    stY = e.currentTarget.y;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function ObjdropinPenta(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();


if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(penta))
{
    trace(e.currentTarget.name);

    var mcName:
    mcName = "S1" + e.currentTarget.name

    trace(mcName.name);
    mcName.visible = false;
    e.currentTarget.visible = false;
}
else
{
    e.currentTarget.x = stX;
    e.currentTarget.y = stY;
}
}
```

I know how to make it separately but i want to make it dynamically

```
mcName.visible = false;
```

this is not working 
where i am missing? Please guide

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: So if your MC name is stored in the variable mcName it would be this[mcName].visible = false;

Comment: thanks Philarmon, can you help me again
my question is that my hitTestObject is a circle but it working as rectangle what should i do for it to work as circle only?

Comment: anyway, i got to know that instead of using hitTestObject, hitTestPoint will be result orianted.

Comment: You need to understand what's a variable and what's an object. Those are 2 different things and by the way you code I can tell you don't understand the difference. A variable points to an object, in your case you want the variable 'mcName' to point to a MovieClip but you make it point to a string: "S1" + e.currentTarget.name. Do you understand that this is a String not a MovieClip?

Comment: yes, thats why i stuck. I will learn what you mentioned, thanks. By the way if i know everything then what reason will bring me here??
I could appreciate if you explain instead of getting me down.